# how can I make a variable which is the result of an equation update in c++?

Tags: c++, spreadsheet, equation

I am making a spreadsheet program out of an array where a cell will automatically update based on the inputs of other cells. This code snippet works fine when the equation cell is initialized, although does not update when the other cells that it depends upon are updated. Is there a way that I can have the equation cell automatically update without a bunch more computation/memory usage?

```cpp
    if (operation == '+') {
        spreadsheet[row][column] = spreadsheet[row1][column1] + spreadsheet[row2][column2];
    } else if (operation == '-') {
        spreadsheet[row][column] = spreadsheet[row1][column1] - spreadsheet[row2][column2];
    } else if (operation == '*') {
        spreadsheet[row][column] = spreadsheet[row1][column1] * spreadsheet[row2][column2];
    } else if (operation == '/') {
        spreadsheet[row][column] = spreadsheet[row1][column1] / spreadsheet[row2][column2];
    }
}
```

Edit: This is an old post, and since then I have found the solution. I stored the equation cell as a reference to other cells so that it takes whatever value is at that memory address instead of whatever was at the memory address when it was initialized. It would still be interesting to know whether there are any better solutions though.

Comment: Did you try walking through with a debugger?

Comment: yes but  I don't know how to use it.

Comment: spreadsheet[row1][column1]  and/or spreadsheet[row2][column2] may be referenced to somewhere empty. First try to find out that refers correct value by printing it (I mean cout) after words try to print the value referred by spreadsheet[row][column]. If all works perfect,  error will be on the way you try to display the value. Apart from that writing whole bunch of code inside switch cases isn't a good practice. If I were you, I would create some methods and call them inside the switch.

Comment: Sorry to everyone who took the time to answer. I found a solution to the problem by using pointers but forgot to say.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to C++, but you need to be able to construct a dependency graph between cells. You may then figure out in which order to do computations when certain cell changes.

There are tricky cases when order matters. Imagine you have cells `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` ... `Z`, and every cell depends on all of the previous ones (i.e. `W` depends on `C`, but `H` doesn't depend on `J`). If you change value of `A`, you must ensure that all of the other cells are computed exactly in order `B->C->D->...->Z`. This can generally be achieved by topological sorting.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to store function instead of value in your matrix, something like:

`std::array<std::array<std::function<Value(), MaxColumn>, MaxRow> spreadsheet;`

```
switch(type) {
case 1:
    //if the user wants to input a number to the cell
    cout << "what number would you like to replace it with?\n";
    cin >> replacenum;
    spreadsheet[row][column] = [=]() { return replacenum; };
    break;
case 2:
    //if the user wants to put an equation in a cell
    cout << "what operator would you like to use? (+,-,*,/,%)\n";
    cin >> operation;
    cout << "enter the row on the first cell\n";
    cin >> row1;
    cout << "enter the column on the first cell\n";
    cin >> column1;
    cout << "enter the row on the second cell\n";
    cin >> row2;
    cout << "enter the column on the second cell\n";
    cin >> column2;
    cout << "calculating...";
    row1--;
    column1--;
    row2--;
    column2--;
    if (operation == '+') {
        spreadsheet[row][column] = [=, &spreadsheet](){ return spreadsheet[row1][column1]() + spreadsheet[row2][column2](); };
    } else if (operation == '-') {
        spreadsheet[row][column] = [=, &spreadsheet](){ return spreadsheet[row1][column1]() - spreadsheet[row2][column2](); };
    } else if (operation == '*') {
        spreadsheet[row][column] = [=, &spreadsheet](){ return spreadsheet[row1][column1]() * spreadsheet[row2][column2](); };
    } else if (operation == '/') {
        spreadsheet[row][column] = [=, &spreadsheet](){ return spreadsheet[row1][column1]() / spreadsheet[row2][column2](); };
    }
}
```

To get value, as you might notice, you have to use `()`.

Care, if you create cycle, you create infinite loop to compute value of a cell.

Comment: Jarod42, when I do that, it gives me error messages saying: assigning to double from incompatible type(it does it when I change it to an integer as well), spreadsheet cannot be captured because it does not have automatic storage duration, called object type double is not a function or a function pointer. Would these be fixed by changing spreadsheet to a void?

Comment: You don't show declarations of your variables... So I use placeholder `Value` in return type in the `std::function`, might probably be `double` or `float`. Possible other issues if `spreadsheet` is member, then you have to capture `this` instead.